# Log4j threshold not working

Tags: logging, log4j

I set the rootlogger level to debug and a package level to ERROR but still the package is logging INFO and DEBUG levels to.. Here is my log properties..

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File = C:\\appl\\logs\\appdir.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%5p] [%C:%M:%L] - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, rollingFile
log4j.logger.net.sf = WARN, rollingFile
log4j.logger.net.sf = ERROR, rollingFile
```

but I see lot of INFO and DEBUG messages from "net.sf" packages on log file.. how do I disable this package logging?

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you've added multiple associations between your loggers and the appender. Child loggers inherit their parent's appenders, so this is simpler and expresses what you mean:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, rollingFile
log4j.logger.net.sf = WARN
```

This will limit `net.sf` to `WARN` and above, and inherits the `rollingfile` appender from the root parent.